# Why does GCC 4.8.2 not propagate 'unused but set' optimization?

Tags: c++, gcc, llvm, compiler-optimization

If a variable is not read from ever, it is obviously optimized out. However, the only store operation on that variable is the result of the only read operation of another variable. So, this second variable should also be optimized out. Why is this not being done?

```
int main() {
  timeval a,b,c;

  // First and only logical use of a
  gettimeofday(&a,NULL);

  // Junk function
  foo();

  // First and only logical use of b
  gettimeofday(&b,NULL);

  // This gets optimized out as c is never read from.
  c.tv_sec = a.tv_sec - b.tv_sec;

  //std::cout << c;
}
```

Aseembly (gcc 4.8.2 with -O3):

```
subq    $40, %rsp
xorl    %esi, %esi
movq    %rsp, %rdi
call    gettimeofday
call    foo()
leaq    16(%rsp), %rdi
xorl    %esi, %esi
call    gettimeofday
xorl    %eax, %eax
addq    $40, %rsp
ret
subq    $8, %rsp
```

Edit: The results are the same for using `rand()` .

Comment: I am not sure this is the answer but I suspect that this happens because `gettimeofday` doesn't have any spec saying that parameter is not used inside that function (thing like `in`/`out` specs). Otherwise not only `a` and `b` but also function call could be optimized out

Comment: If I use simple `a = rand(); foo(); b= rand();`. It also gives the same result.

Comment: @underscore_d I'm not sure I understand you. I meant not "variable wasn't **altered** in some function" but "wasn't **used** within function"

Comment: nvm, I think I might've been talking nonsense :-) @themagicalyang Please define "that variable" and "this second variable". i.e. What do you expect to happen here? It's difficult to answer a question when it's not clear what it's asking.

Comment: How would the compiler optimize out the other variables when you pass their addresses to `gettimeofday`? It can hardly pass `NULL` instead.

Comment: @SebastianRedl As I said above rand() also doesn't get optimized out.

Comment: @themagicalyang The call to `rand()` or the variable the result is assigned to? Because the call to `rand()` modifies a global variable and thus can't be optimized out.

Answer (score 3):

There's no store operation! There *are* 2 calls to `gettimeofday`, yes, but that is a *visible effect*. And visible effects are precisely the things that may not be optimized away.